# Can tkinter menus send the event in which they were called?

Tags: python, events, tkinter, event-handling, tk-toolkit

Below is a popup menu command I would like to send event data through. I want the event for its x and y data so I know what cell of the ttk styled treeview (being used as a table) to operate on. Currently it calls the "self.toggle_sort_bool" method but I want it to call the function at the end "self.sort_children(event, cur_tree_children)," but do not because I need to figure out passing/receiving the event here. Note: I know that sending is automatic but receiving is not. Am I overlooking something?

```
self.heading_popup_menu = tk.Menu(self.treeview, tearoff=0)
self.heading_popup_menu.add_command(label="Reverse Sort", command=self.toggle_sort_bool)
```

Here is where the journey of the event begins with a right click on the ttk styled treeview.

```
self.treeview.bind('<Button-3>', self.pop_up_right_click_detail)
```

The event's x_root and y_root are sent to the tk_popup. Should/can I overload this to send the whole event? It seems the x and y of the event in the root are sent to tell the popup where to...pop up.

```
def pop_up_right_click(self, event):
        try:
            self.heading_popup_menu.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
        finally:
            self.heading_popup_menu.grab_release()
```

Here is the function I want to call from the menu command.

```
def sort_children(self, event, cur_tree_children):
    region = self.treeview.identify("region", event.x, event.y)

    if region == "heading":
        #get column number
        col = self.treeview.identify_column(event.x)
        col = int(re.sub('\D', '', col))

        col_names = cur_tree_children.pop(0)
        cur_tree_children.sort(reverse=self.reverse_sort_bool.get(), key=lambda tup: self.sort_disparate_types(tup[col-1])) #toggle reverse somehow
        cur_tree_children.insert(0, col_names)
        self.depopulate_tree()
        self.populate_tree()
```

Is it possible to send an event through a menu? I am confused because of how disjointed the--for lack of better terminology--events are in calling a function through a right click pop up menu. While this is all part of one big GUI class, I do not want to use class instance variables to communicate the target cell data because I believe that is messy and bad practice and thus should be avoided wherever possible.

P.S. If I had enough reputation I would make the tag BryanOakley and post this under it.

Comment: Yes, it's possible to send anything anywhere. If you show use a [mcve] then I can show you how.

Comment: I think this is a simple question asked in an overcomplicated manner.

Comment: @Nae I have to agree, I'm going back to the drawing board to rework it and will have either the solution or ask it better tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to do what you want is to modify the menu command immediately before displaying the menu. You can either define `postcommand` which defines a function that is run before the menu is displayed, or you can do the modification in the code that causes the menu to pop up.

Since you want to pass the event to the function, the best solution is to modify the menu right before popping it up since that function already has the event object.

Another other option would be to have your function set some instance variables, rather than modifying the menu. You can then reference those instance variables in the function called from the menu.

Since you said you don't want to use instance variables, here's an example showing how to modify the menu:

```
def show_popup(self, event):
    self.popup.entryconfig("Do Something", command=lambda: self.something(event))
    self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)
```

### Example

Here's a complete working example. The code displays a window with a treeview widget which has some dummy data. If you right-click over the treeview you will see a menu with one item. When you click that item it will display information in a label about where the click occurred.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.treeview = ttk.Treeview(self.root, columns=("one", "two", "three"))
        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, width=40)

        self.label.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
        self.treeview.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        self.popup = tk.Menu(self.root, tearoff=False)
        self.popup.add_command(label="Do something")

        self.treeview.bind('<Button-3>', self.show_popup)

        for column in self.treeview.cget("columns"):
            self.treeview.column(column, width=50)

        for i in range(10):
            values = ("a%s" % i, "b%s" %i, "c%s" %i)
            self.treeview.insert('', 'end', text="Item %s" % i, values=values)

    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_popup(self, event):
        self.popup.entryconfig("Do something", command=lambda: self.do_something(event))
        self.popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root)

    def do_something(self, event):
        region = self.treeview.identify("region", event.x, event.y)
        col = self.treeview.identify_column(event.x)

        message = "you clicked %s,%s region=%s column=%s" % (event.x, event.y, region, col)
        self.label.configure(text=message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Example().start()
```

Comment: Could you please add an explanation on what the example code does independent of the question? I'm having a hard time understanding it.

Comment: @Nae: I don't know what you mean. It doesn't do anything but present a treeview that has a right-click menu. I've added a very short description to the answer.

Comment: Where the initial click, right click, occurred right?

Comment: One thing I must add: for entryconfig you must (at least in the python 3.6 build of tkinter) speficy the index of the menu item as the first argument, which in your example would be 0 because you only have one item and it is the first menu on the item. Thanks Bryan!

Comment: @AlecKeyserWhite: in my example, "Do something" is the index. You can supply a numerical index, but you can also supply the item text.

Comment: Ahh I see! My mistake Bryan.